# Custom block based off core block using filter

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, block-editor

I would like to create a new block, "Custom Paragraph," based on the "core/paragraph" block but with the color and typography options removed in the inspector controls. I've written the following plugin but upon activation, the "Custom Paragraph" block does not appear in my available block list.

My knowledge of creating a custom block using PHP is limited and any help would be appreciated.

````
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Paragraph Block
Plugin URI: https://example.com/
Description: A custom paragraph block.
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Name
Author URI: https://example.com/
*/

function custom_paragraph_block_settings( $settings, $blockname ) {
    if ( $blockname !== 'core/paragraph-custom' ) {
        return $settings;
    }

    // Remove 'color' and 'typography' settings from the inspector controls.
    unset( $settings['supports']['color'] );
    unset( $settings['supports']['typography'] );

    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'register_block_type_args', 'custom_paragraph_block_settings', 10, 2 );

function register_custom_paragraph_block() {
    $args = array(
        'attributes'      => array(),
        'render_callback' => 'render_custom_paragraph_block',
        'supports'        => array(
            'align' => true, 
        ),
    );

    register_block_type( 'core/paragraph-custom', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_paragraph_block' );



function render_custom_paragraph_block( $attributes ) {
    // Extract the 'content' and 'customAttribute' attributes from the $attributes array.
    $content = isset( $attributes['content'] ) ? $attributes['content'] : '';
    $customAttribute = isset( $attributes['customAttribute'] ) ? $attributes['customAttribute'] : '';

    return '<p class="custom-paragraph">' . wp_kses_post( $content ) . '</p>';
}```
````

Comment: would it not be easier to create a block style or a block variant? Then your new block would gracefully fallback to a standard paragraph if your code was removed, core would offer block transforms, you would get style previews if you used styles, there's even a chance you could do it with zero JS in some circumstances. Not only that, by creating a new block your new block won't be in the list of allowed blocks that other blocks use, meaning they cannot be inserted in the same places reducing compatibility

Comment: e.g. if the goal is to provide a version of the paragraph that always looks a specific way then you could use this from PHP https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_style/

Comment: @TomJNowell, my goal is to create duplicate copies of the core blocks with the formatting and customization options removed for "editors" to use. I would like to keep the core block settings unchanged for "admin" level users.

I have tried copying core blocks, like [table](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/table), and plugin the content into a directory from the @create/block tool but have not been successful. 

Is there a better process of copying then customizing existing core blocks?

Comment: you can turn almost all the options off via `theme.json` or the associated PHP filter, e.g. padding/margins/box shadows/font sizes/etc are all controllable and can be restricted to specific values/ranges/disabled entirely. E.g. you can force all images to have rounded corners and remove the setting in a theme or add extra styling that's applied without any ability to remove it entirely from JSON